# postgresql cannot connect to server locally

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1

I've just installed the postgresql 9.1 on one brand new Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server with the following command : 
**sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev** 
The installation proceeded without errors. Basically I should be able to connect to local server, however when I tap the command **psql**, the following errors appears :

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  Is the
>   server running locally and accepting  connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I've searched a lot of posts online, but cannot solve problem (very often, the mentioned directory doesn't exist on my server). Can anyone suggests some solutions ? Thanks !

Comment: Did you start the postgres server? `psql` is a client, the server must be running when you attempt to connect to it. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

Comment: Have you tried `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.1 start` or `sudo systemctl start postgresql` to start the server ?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you  did not install postgresql successfully.
Please follow here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get purge postgresql* # ending * is important
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

It will fix your problem.

Comment: This worked for me, even **without** adding the `ppa:pitti/postgresql` repository. I guess I just needed the `libpq-dev` package.